# Warning: Passing null instead of ... Is this intentional?

Tags: python, warnings, pycharm, python-3.4

In the code below i get a weak warning from Pycharm:

```
class ClassA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('A init')


class ClassB(object):    
    def __init__(self):
        print('B init')

    def f(self):
        a = ClassA

        class C(a):    
            def __init__(self):
                # Here i get the weak warning.
                # ...       |     .......
                # ...       v     .......
                a.__init__(self)
                print('C init')

        return C

a_class = ClassB().f()
print('hello')
a_class()
```

**Warning message**:

> Passing null instead of tests.experiments.ClassA. Is this intentional?
>
> This inspection checks for calls of a method by class while passing an instance of a different class as self parameter.
>
> ```
> foo = Foo()  
> Bar.baz(foo, *more)
> ```
>
> Sometimes this may be intentional and correct. But when unintentional this leads to subtle bugs.

I can't find any relevant information about this warning. What sort of bug could it cause? (an example would be nice, if possible)

Comment: Curious about your intent here, but does replacing the `a.__init__(self)` with `super(C, self).__init__()` replicate the same functionality for you?

Comment: @Jkdc Yep, nothing changes in the program output when i change it to `super()`. The warning does go away though.

Comment: it's complaining because you are trying to pass 'instance' of `C` to the constructor of `a` as a `self` which ought to be `a` not `C`, with `super()` you make sure you pass correct object - also in python 3.4 you can just use `super().__init__()`